# $p\equiv 1\pmod 4\Rightarrow p=a^2+b^2$ and $p\equiv 1\pmod 8\Rightarrow p=a^2+2b^2$, what about for $p\equiv 1\pmod {2^n}$ in general

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, integer-partitions

Primes $p$ with $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$ can be written as $p=a^2+b^2$ for some integers $a,b$. For $p\equiv 1\pmod 8$ we have $p=a^2+2b^2$. Can primes that satisfy $p\equiv 1\pmod{2^n}$ for $n>3$ be written in a similar form -- for example $p=a^2+4b^2$ for $n=4$?

Comment: for $n=4$ and $p=a^2+4b^2$: [A094407](http://oeis.org/A094407) and [A131204](http://oeis.org/A131204). gp-code `forprime(p=3,10000,n=4;if(Mod(p,2^n)==1,if(#thue('x^2+4,p),print1(p", "))))`.

Comment: For $n=4$ it's true because we can express $p$ as sum of squares and one of them should be even.

Comment: The same works for $n=5$ (consider $a^2+2b^2$ modulo 8)

Answer (score 6):

it gets harder, and we cannot just impose congruence conditions.

Added: one thing I've not seen in print is this: as soon as $p \equiv 1 \pmod 8,$ we find that $-1$ is a fourth power mod $p,$ and
$$ z^4  + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p  $$
has four distinct roots.

A prime can be expressed as $p = x^2 + 32 y^2$   if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 8$  and
$$ z^4 - 2 z^2 + 2 \equiv 0 \pmod p  $$
has four distinct roots.

A prime can be expressed as $p = x^2 + 64 y^2$   if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 8$  and
$$ z^4 - 2  \equiv 0 \pmod p  $$
has four distinct roots.

The 64 result can be found under "biquadratic reciprocity." Both results may be due to Gauss, but were not published until Jacobi and Eisenstein.

Answer (score 0):

Let prime $p=a^2+2^{n-2}\cdot b^2\equiv1\pmod{2^n}$, where $n>4$ and $a,b$ is integers.

Then sequence $(n, min(p))$=`(5,97), (6,193), (7,257), (8,257), (9,18433), (10,18433), (11,18433), (12,65537), (13,1097729), (14,65537), (15,1179649), (16,65537), (17,1179649), (18,26214401), (19,117964801), (20,26214401), (21,169869313), (22,104857601), ...`.

gp-code:

```
nminp()=
{
 for(n=5,100,
  forprime(p=3,10^9,
   m= 2^n;
   if(Mod(p,m)==1,
    if(#thue('x^2+m/4, p),
     print1("("n","p"), ");
     break()
    )
   )
  )
 )
};
```