# $2^n$-th rational reciprocity laws

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, class-field-theory, quadratic-reciprocity, gauss-sums

Let $p,q$ be odd coprime primes. We are familiar with the quadratic reciprocity law:

$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{4}}$.

This is generalized (see for example Reciprocity Laws be Lemmermeyer) to quartic ($2^2$-th power) and octic ($2^3$-th power) reciprocity laws:

Let $p,q\equiv 1\mod 4$, both quadratic residues modulo the other. Then we can write $p=a^2+b^2$, $q=c^2+b^2$ with $b,d$ even and see:

$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)_4\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)_4=\left(\frac{ac-bd}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{ac-bd}{q}\right)$, where $\left(\frac{\bullet}{\bullet}\right)_4$ is the $4$-th power analogue of the Legendre symbol.

Similarly let $p,q\equiv 1\mod 8$, both quartic residues modulo the other. Then we can write $p=a^2+b^2=A^2+2B^2$, $q=c^2+d^2=C^2+2D^2$ with $B,D$ even and see:

$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)_8\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)_8=\left(\frac{aB-bA}{q}\right)_4\left(\frac{cD-dC}{q}\right)$, where $\left(\frac{\bullet}{\bullet}\right)_8$ is the $8$-th power analogue of the Legendre symbol.

One sees a nice pattern emerging and may hope that this continues for $2^n$-th residues. However, no references I can find list laws for a higher $n$. It seems to get harder, for example maybe due to [the difficulty of partitioning $p$ into new weighted sums of squares for $n\geq 3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3785734/p-equiv-1-pmod-4-rightarrow-p-a2b2-and-p-equiv-1-pmod-8-rightarrow-p-a22)*.

**Questions**:

Are there known higher (rational) reciprocity laws for $2^n$-th powers?

Is it known there are 'no' higher rational reciprocity laws?

*Does class field theory have any way of partitioning for $n\geq 3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $16$th powers see [Leonard and Williams](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa33/aa3344.pdf). For a general law in function fields, see [Hamahata](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00013-016-0990-3.pdf). Patterns for $n \le 3$ are misleading since ${\mathbb Q}(\zeta_8)$ is a biquadratic number field, whereas ${\mathbb Q}(\zeta_{2^n})$ for $n \ge 4$ is not.